# Не распознается база данных newDB.sql Error: 1049

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Я уже задавал этот вопрос, но кто-то кликнул -1.
Прошу этого не делать, не вникнув в вопрос. Если он Вам не ясен, не лишайте более опытных разработчиков возможности увидеть его и дать профессиональный совет

И так, при использовании MySQL2Sqlite [скрипта](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776) и конвертировании файла newDB.sql в файл newDB.sqlite с помощью команды

```
sudo ./mysql2sqlite.sh --no-data -u root -p newDB.sql | sqlite3 newDB.sqlite
```

в терминале Linux выдается ошибка

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: "Unknown database 'newDB.sql'" when selecting the database
```

Файл mysql2sqlite.sh лежит в той же папке, где и дамп базы данных myDB.sql

Будьте добрый советом! В сети не могу найти решения проблемы!

PS: [данное](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883352/mysqldump-error-1049-unknown-database-db-when-selecting-the-database) решение не могу применить либо по причине того, что не понимаю, о чем речь, либо видимо это не касается вопроса. У меня опыт разработки всего 10 дней

Comment: Оно говорит, что не находит в вашем MySQL-сервере базу под названием 'newDB.sql`. Вы уверены, что искомая база называется именно так?

Comment: @Yaant, файл newDB.sql находится в папке где и скрипт mysql2sqlite для преобразования. Я так понимаю, файл newDB.sql надо пенести на сервер MySQL. Я просто не знаю, где этот сервер располагается. В папке /var/lib/mysql/ ???

Comment: Приведенная в вопросе команда подключается к серверу MySQL, и конвертирует указанную ей базу в базу SQLite. Никакие файлы тут не участвуют.
Если у Вас уже есть SQL-файл, то просто скормите его SQLite'у, как-то так, видимо: `cat newDB.sql | sqlite3 newDB.sqlite` (знатоки Линукса меня поправят, если что)

Comment: @Yaant, сделал, однако получил кучу ошибок типа Error: near line 10: near "SET": syntax error
Error: near line 11: near "SET": syntax error
Error: near line 29: near "ENGINE": syntax error
Error: near line 46: no such table: Students
Error: near line 69: no such table: Students
Error: near line 79: near "MODIFY": syntax error

Comment: Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Yaant, 
Внутри .sql все таблицы есть. Текстовый файл все прекрасно показывает

Comment: А, вы выгрузили скрипт из MySQL, и он в так и остался в формате MySQL. Теперь Вам надо его преобразовать в формат SQLite. Соответственно, Вам надо  либо переделать скрипт mysql2sqlite, так, чтобы он вместо обращения к базе брал уже существующий файл, либо забыть про файл, и натравить скрипт непосредственно на базу.

Comment: @Yaant, хорошо выступил. оформи ответом

Comment: @Enoch, если у вас есть возможость подлкючиться к MariaDB/MySQL DB, то испраьте команду: `sudo ./mysql2sqlite.sh --no-data -u root -p<root's_password> <mysql_database_name> | sqlite3 /path/to/newDB.sqlite`. Если у вас есть только `newDB.sql` файл и нет возможности подключиться к базе данных, то можно заменить в скрипте "mysql2sqlite.sh":  `mysqldump  --compatible=ansi --skip-extended-insert --compact` --> `cat `. После этого можно вызывать так: `./mysql2sqlite.sh newDB.sql | sqlite3 /path/to/newDB.sqlite`

Comment: @nörbörnën не, на ответ тут куда больше тянет комментарий от MaxU, а у меня были так, общие соображения :)

Comment: @MaxU, под подключением к MariaDB я понимаю выполнение команды mysql -u root -p в терминале. То есть в командной строке появляеться приветствие Welcome to the MariaDB monitor и так далее и командная строка выглядит как MariaDB [(none)]>. То есть там не командная строка Линукс и в этом режиме команды линукс не работают. Там ведь уже декларативный язык SQL. То есть там в этом случае выдает кучу ошибок. Поэтому, затрудняюсь правильно выполнить совет. По поводу замены строки не сработало...

Comment: @Yaant, изменить  mysql2sqlite не могу, так как не понимаю, что там написано. Я не программист, только делаю первые шаги. Я как раз и пытаюсь сделать формат sqlite, но не могу понять как это сделать. А онлайн конвертеры использовать не решение проблемы. Поэтому и возник вопрос

Comment: @MaxU, Вот последовательность команд если не запускать MariaDB: sudo ./mysql2sqlite.sh myWork.sql | sqlite3 /path/to/newDB.sqlite ОТВЕТ В ТЕРМИНАЛЕ
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
И завис...

Comment: @Enoch, а что не сработало с исправленной командой из моего предыдущего комментария?

Comment: @MaxU, команды Линукс не работают в командной строке для MariaDB, а если не запускать MariaDB и просто использовать преобразование в командной строке Линукс, которое вы предложили, то как я и писал коментарием выше, преобразование не выполняется. Терминал просто ожидает следующей команды и все

Comment: Можете запостить целиком команду которую вы запускали? (Только пароль замените )

Comment: Я надеюсь вы догадались заменить “<root’s_password>” на ваш истинный пароль? 

Comment: @MaxU, sudo ./mysql2sqlite.sh --no-data -u root -p ТУТ ПАРОЛЬ myWork.sql | sqlite3 /путь/newDB.sqlite

Comment: Не работает ничего

Comment: ОТВЕТ sudo: ./mysql2sqlite.sh: command not found

Comment: @MaxU я нахожусь в той же директории, где и все необходимые файлы

Comment: паскалевский файл сделан исполнительным chmod -x mysql2sqlite.sh

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113718/discussion-on-question-by-enoch-----newdb-sql-error-104).

Comment: [Руководство](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) по написанию скрипта на Python для работы с СУБД MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
sudo ./mysql2sqlite.sh --no-data -u root -p'<ПАРОЛЬ для root>' <имя_базы_данных_для_экспорта> | sqlite3 /path/to/newDB.db
```

Пример (если пароль="myPa$$w()rd", имя базы данных - "mydb"):

```
sudo ./mysql2sqlite.sh --no-data -u root -p'myPa$$w()rd' mydb | sqlite3 /path/to/newDB.db
```

Comment: До пароля даже не доходит дело. Ответ в Терминале: sudo: ./mysql2sqlite.sh: command not found

Comment: Я нахожусь при этом в той же дериктории, что и mysql2sqlite.sh

Comment: @Enoch, ну попробуйте указать полный путь или вообще без `sudo` (но я не уверен на счет прав доступа - если доступ к БД есть только у `root`, то придется использовать `sudo`)

Comment: [Руководство](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) по написанию скрипта на Python для работы с СУБД MySQL

Comment: @Enoch, неплохое руководство, но к сожалению оно не имеет ничего общего со сформулированным вами вопросом. В вопросе нет ни слова о Python. Соответственно для тех, кто попадет сюда из поисковиков данная ссылка не принесет никакой пользы